# Is there a PHP library that facilitates manipulating html elements in a similar fashion to jquery?

Tags: php

PHP string manipulation functions are very counterintuitive and clunky, at least for me, and everytime I need to manipulate some html code before outputting it it takes too much time.

I was wondering if there was any PHP library that helps with this, preferably in a similar way to jQuery: retrieving and manipulating element attributes, selecting all the attributes with a  given class, etc.

Comment: I don't know what kind of project you need this for, but as a general case: If you need to manipulate HTML in such way in PHP, there's a good chance you're doing it wrong. You should manipulate the pure data first, then build the HTML based on it, not the other way around.

Comment: @Juhana: what about mash-up data from websites that don't provide public API?

Comment: @juhana: in this case, the pure data is HTML. This is for a CMS which am trying to optimize, so I am trying to apply some filters to the HTML that users upload. They are mainly cosmetic, so I prefer to leave the html in the database as it is and filter it before output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or [querypath](http://querypath.org/). Here is a comprehensive tutorial about [querypath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-querypath/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX01&S_CMP=HP).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Dom Parser in PHP :

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Sweet, I didnt know about this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be manipulating the HTML as a DOMdocument and using XPath (quite similar to jQuery selectors)  to select the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Next to what [silent answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553965/is-there-a-php-library-that-facilitates-manipulating-html-elements-in-a-similar-f/7553989#7553989), there is also [FluentDOM](http://fluentdom.github.com/) which is not exactly jQuery mimicking, but provides fluent interfaces based on [`DomDocument`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).